# Covariance of two sample means

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, mean, covariance

I am trying to derive the covariance of two sample means and get confused at one point. Given is a sample of size $n$ with paired dependent observations $x_i$ and $y_i$ as realizations of RVs $X$ and $Y$ and sample means $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$. I try to derive $cov(\bar{x},\bar{y})$.

I am relatively sure the result should be

$$cov(\bar{x},\bar{y})=\frac{1}{n}cov(X,Y)$$

However I arrive at

$$cov(\bar{x},\bar{y})=E(\bar{x}\bar{y})-\mu_x\mu_y = E\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\sum x_i \sum y_i\right) -\mu_x\mu_y
=\frac{1}{n^2} n^2 E(x_i y_i) -\mu_x\mu_y=cov(X,Y)$$

I used

$$E\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\sum x_i \sum y_i\right)=\frac{1}{n^2} E\left(x_1y_1+x_2y_1+\cdots + x_ny_n\right)=\frac{1}{n^2} n^2 E(x_iy_i)$$

Somewhere should be a flaw in my thinking.

Comment: I think your reasoning is essentially correct: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59546/estimating-the-covariance-of-the-means-from-two-samples, that is, $\mathrm{cov}(\bar{x},\bar{y}) = \mathrm{cov}(X,Y)$

Comment: So the difference is the assumption about covariances in paired and independent samples. The upper result is that for paired samples, the lower that for independent samples, where $E(x_iy_j)=E(x_i)E(y_j)$ when $i \ne j$

Comment: If you are comfortable with deriving the fact that the variance of the sample mean is $1/n$ times the variance, then the result is immediate because [covariances are variances](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/142472). As far as your mistake goes, note that $\text{cov}(x_i,y_j)=0$ for $i\ne j$. It also helps to know that whenever you are working with covariances or variances you may always assume the means are zero, because these are *central* moments that don't depend on the means at all.

Comment: What I do not yet fully understand is why it holds that $cov(x_i,y_j)=0$ for $i≠j$ when I have paired samples, but it does not hold when I have independent samples (?). Can you explain?

Comment: Your use of the term "sample" implicitly means $(x_i,y_i)$ is independent of $(x_j,y_j)$ for $i\ne j$. From this it is immediate that their covariances (if they exist) must be zero.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Covariance is a *bilinear* function meaning that
> $$
> \operatorname{cov}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_iC_i,  \sum_{j=1}^m b_jD_j\right) 
> = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m a_i b_j\operatorname{cov}(C_i,D_j).$$
> There is no need to mess with means etc.

Applying this to the question of the covariance of the sample means
of $n$ independent paired samples $(X_i, Y_i)$ (note: the *pairs*
are independent bivariate random variables; we are not claiming
that $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are independent random variables), we have that
\begin{align}
\operatorname{cov}\left(\bar{X},\bar{Y}\right)
&= \operatorname{cov}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i,
 \frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^n Y_j\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n 
\operatorname{cov} (X_i, Y_j)\\
&= \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n  
\operatorname{cov} (X_i, Y_i)
&\scriptstyle{\text{since $X_i$ and $Y_j$ are independent,
and thus uncorrelated, for
$i \neq j$}}\\
&= \frac 1n\operatorname{cov} (X, Y)
\end{align}

---

As noted below in a comment by flow2k, although $\operatorname{cov}(\bar{X},\bar{Y})$ is smaller than $\operatorname{cov}({X},{Y})$ by a factor of $n$, the (Pearson) correlation coefficients are the same:  $\rho_{\bar{X},\bar{Y}} = \rho_{X,Y}$ !! Previously I had never given the correlation coefficients any thought at all.

Comment: I think they are $n^2$ terms, but $n(n-1)$ cancle with $\mu_x\mu_y$ due to independence.

Comment: The quoted section above "Covariance is a bilinear function..." - where is this quoted from?

Comment: @flow2k The first "quoted" paragraph of my answer is not specifically a quotation in the sense that I wrote it myself without looking at a textbook or paper etc while doing so, but the first sentence (possibly in _exactly_ the same words) can be found in many textbooks.  The second sentence of the "quoted" paragraph  is proudly my own words; textbook writers (or their copyeditors) and journal paper writers and journal editors don't use such informal language.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's interesting the *correlation coefficient* of the sample means remains unchanged.

Comment: I had never thought about correlation coefficients at all!  I will incorporate this information into my answer (with credit to you).

Answer (score 6):

I think the algebra issue is resolved with the following:

\begin{align}{1 \over n^2}E\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \sum_{i=1}^n y_i\right)&={1 \over n^2}E\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i +\sum_{i\ne j}x_i y_j\right)\\&={1 \over n^2}(n(Cov(x_i,y_i)+\mu_X \mu_Y)+n(n-1)\mu_X \mu_Y)\\&={1 \over n^2}(n Cov(x_i,y_i)+n^2 \mu_X \mu_Y))\\&=Cov(x_i,y_i)/n+ \mu_X \mu_Y\end{align}

Comment: I think the answer would need to add that the second equation holds due to independence of $x_i$ and $y_j$ for $i \ne j$.

Comment: Yes, that is essential.