# covariance estimate for the means of two unpaired dependent samples

Tags: estimation, mean, covariance, standard-error

I have two dependent samples $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ of $s$ and $t$ observations, respectively, that is $$
\mathbf{X} = \{X_1, \dots, X_s\} \;, \\
\mathbf{Y} = \{Y_1, \dots, Y_t\} \;.
$$
For example, you could imagine that there is a random variable Z and functions $f, g$ such that $\mathbf{X} = f(Z), \mathbf{Y} = g(Z)$.

My quantities of interest are the sample means $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{Y}$ of $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$, respectively.

Is there a standard estimate for the covariance $\mathrm{Cov}[\bar{X}, \bar{Y}]$ of the sample means?

Comment: I am happy for suggestions for a better title and tags!

Comment: The answer can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163583/covariance-of-two-sample-means)

Comment: @AlejandroCelis That's just the simple case of paired observations.